# Looping a linear regression function and appending the resulting gradients as a new column

Tags: r, linear-regression, lm

I have data for 293 sites for 11 years and am wanting to run a linear model on each site over all the years, extract the gradient value obtained and append it to the data.

I have a df with all the data from all the years in, only_means and a vector with the years c(2005:2015), called years

```
        2005   2006   2007   2008   2009   2010   2011   2012   2013   2014   2015

   1    20.8   16.5   21.2   24.6   23.2   26.4   23.8   24.9   20.3   19.5   NA
   2    21.9   19.5   19.8   25.9   25.6   26.7   24.4   22.9   21.8   18.6   15.8
   3    33.7   44.2   44.8   51.9   59.6   61.4   57.7   61.7   46.5   48.3   45.5
   4    41.5   48.0   47.1   53.9   67.6   58.3   62.0   53.4   50.7   52.2   47.1
   5    40.7   45.9   39.9   41.3   47.1   47.2   46.0   41.6   35.8   37.7   37.4
   6    37.5   38.3   37.1   44.3   49.4   52.6   48.0   44.2   35.9   37.4   37.5
```

Also if possible I'd like to get hold of an R^2 value for each model and append that too

Edit: Independent variable is the year, dependent variables are the readings provided

Expected output is the gradient of the line of best fit through the points

Comment: "run a linear model on each site over all the years," whats your DV and IVs? It's not entirely clear from your question. Also, please provide your expected output

Comment: DV is the year at the top, IV is the data for each year for each site, so I want to create a linear regression model where the data on each row is the IV

Comment: The statistics of the model is unclear. It almost sounds like this is suppose to be a time series model.

Comment: @DataTx my supervisor (I'm at university) wants to see what the average change per year has been, so for that I thought it would be easier to run a linear regression on each site and find the gradient (also, I'm fairly new to R and programming in general, so apologies if my question is unclear)

Comment: @BenRichmond "IV is the data for each site". data of what exactly? It also seems like `year` should be the IV and the readings (whatever that is) should be the DV if "average change per year" is what you are looking for.

Comment: @UseR yes, sorry, been a long day

Comment: @BenRichmond You might want to edit your question then. Maybe also give a brief description of what your data is measuring.

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't get you the R-squared value per site, but `lmList()` will fit linear regressions by group, if you have them in long format:

```
dd <- read.table(header=TRUE,check.names=FALSE,row.names=1,text="
    2005   2006   2007   2008   2009   2010   2011   2012   2013   2014   2015

   1    20.8   16.5   21.2   24.6   23.2   26.4   23.8   24.9   20.3   19.5   NA
   2    21.9   19.5   19.8   25.9   25.6   26.7   24.4   22.9   21.8   18.6   15.8
   3    33.7   44.2   44.8   51.9   59.6   61.4   57.7   61.7   46.5   48.3   45.5
   4    41.5   48.0   47.1   53.9   67.6   58.3   62.0   53.4   50.7   52.2   47.1
   5    40.7   45.9   39.9   41.3   47.1   47.2   46.0   41.6   35.8   37.7   37.4
   6    37.5   38.3   37.1   44.3   49.4   52.6   48.0   44.2   35.9   37.4   37.5
")
```

Convert wide to long format:

```
dd$site <- factor(rownames(dd))
dd_long <- tidyr::gather(dd,year,value,-site,convert=TRUE)
```

Fit:

```
fit <- lme4::lmList(value~year|site,data=dd_long)
## Call: lme4::lmList(formula = value ~ year | site, data = dd_long) 
## Coefficients:
##   (Intercept)       year
## 1   -394.3945  0.2072727
## 2    667.1091 -0.3209091
## 3  -1743.9000  0.8927273
## 4   -842.4727  0.4454545
## 5   1176.6091 -0.5645455
## 6    202.8182 -0.0800000
```

Comment: The R-squared is just `summary(fit)$r.squared`.

Comment: yes, but I think (?) that's a pooled r-squared rather than a year-by-year summary